# NSTimer not running

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I've got a program in which I want to code a timer which checks wether the user is idle or not. For that I wrote following code:

```
    if (!idleTimer) {
      NSLog(@"make");
      idleTimer=[[NSTimer alloc]initWithFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10.0]interval:10 target:self selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
      NSLog(@"madetimer with: %f, %@", idleTimer.timeInterval, idleTimer.fireDate);
}else {
      NSLog(@"no reset timer: %f", idleTimer.timeInterval);
      if (fabs([idleTimer.fireDate timeIntervalSinceNow]) < 9) {
         NSLog(@"reset");
         [idleTimer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];
    }
}
```

But somehow my logs show that the interval is always 0.0000 . Which means that something is wrong here. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ive never seen a timer look so complicated.  try this:

write a method that checks if the user is idle (lets say idleChecker)

then make the timer repeatable and calls that method idleChecker

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(idleChecker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

remember to declare the idleChecker method in the .h file

take note if u want to stop the timer event then you need to maintain a reference to it

```
NSTimer aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(idleChecker) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

then to stop it

```
[aTimer invalidate];
```

as for checking if its running i would just stick a nslog message in there stating something like "check for idle user"

Comment: The thing is: This is the method checking if the user is idle or not. As soon as the (UIResponder*)nextResponder method is executed this method gets called which then either makes a new timer if not already there or checks if the user was idle for over 9 seconds. If that is so then another method gets executed.

Comment: i would separate it out though.  and just schedule the timer at the same point your calling this.